# Setting hierarchy of overlapping Divs without position: absolute

Tags: html, css

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76xp2/)

In simple case of overlap of divs

```
<div id='first'>
    first
</div>

<div id='second'>
    second
</div>
```

css:-

```
#second {
    margin-top: -18px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

How do you ensure the `second` div shows over the `first` div, with `#first` not visible (in overlapping region)?

I do not want to make any div `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use z-index. Make the second one a higher z-index

Comment: @SangramSingh it only needs a `position` declaration, you could use `position: relative;` as well as a `z-index` http://jsfiddle.net/76xp2/1/

Answer (score 1):

Like Chausser said, use z-index and also position:relative;

http://jsfiddle.net/xreVf/4/

```
#second {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```